# Standardize table identifiers/names and merge them efficiently

Tags: classification, identifiability, tables, string-count

I hope this is the right place to ask the following question.

I have N tables (N>1000). The rows (all, or some of them) of each table may (or may not) be merged with other rows in other tables, following a specific process that is irrelevant here. Every table has the same columns.

At the end of the process, I have a single, huge, master table.
In this master table, each row is the product of 0, 1, or more mergers.

For each row, I need to find a way to identify from what tables it comes from. For example:

If a specific row is the product of a row from table "A" and another row in table "B", then I need a key/name/identifier like "A+B" or "AB". However, since the mergers can even be like >1000, this will result in a too-long string.
In addition, the current table names are not just "A" or "B" but they are longer strings.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order the tables by how often they appear in mergers. Then assign to each table a bit in a bit-sequence of length $N$, according to this order, i.e. the most frequent table will get the left-most bit. Next, assign to each row the bit sequence that has bit $k$ set if and only if the table belonging to this bit is part of the merger of this row. Then truncate those bit-sequences by removing padding zeros on the right.